# At what point does AnalyserNode execute its FFT?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm trying to write an autocorrelation algorithm using the Web Audio API. Autocorrelation is only dependent on data in the time domain, and not the frequency domain, thus I'm only utilizing `getByteTimeDomainData()`.  I am having a hard time finding info on how the AnalyserNode is implemented.  From what I read in the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode) I am unclear if the FFT is run only when `getByteFrequencyData()` is called, or if it would get run no matter what. Large FFT's are very expensive, so I don't want them running willy nilly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the specification, I would say the expectation is to compute the FFT when you ask for it.
[`getByteFrequencyData()`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-analysernode-getbytefrequencydata):

> The most recent `fftSize` frames are used in computing the frequency data.

and if you ask for it too often, it will even give back a cached result:

> If another call to `getByteFrequencyData()` or `getFloatFrequencyData()` occurs within the same render quantum as a previous call, the current frequency data is not updated with the same data. Instead, the previously computed data is returned.

This wording also suggests that calculation is supposed to happen on request.

Comment: Yes it happens on request.  But if you're doing autocorrelations, the FFT results should be irrelevant to you.  You probably want to use `getFloatTimeDomainData` to get the time data.

Comment: @RaymondToy I think OP wanted to know if it is "safe" to use AnalyserNode in the sense that it will not keep FFT-ing everything it encounters.

Comment: Your answer is correct. It's on demand. But I guess the spec doesn't prevent you from constantly doing FFTs even if they're not needed and you only get use the time domain data.

Comment: @RaymondToy, yes, I was thinking about it too. If an implementation really wants to, it can calculate the FFT at each "render quantum", and still meet with the specs.